# Apache Solr Escape Query

Tags: php, solr, search-engine, solarium

I'm using Apache Solr with [Solarium](http://www.solarium-project.org/) client library for PHP.

The problem is special character, a dash (`-`).

When I have a dash in my search query, I don't get any matches.

I tried to solve this by using `Solarium_Query_Helper::escapeTerm()`. But I don't get any matches again. The dash is being escaped with a backslash `\`.

What is the solution for this problem?

I was thinking about escaping all fields when indexing, but that doesn't sound like a good idea.

Here is the part of my `schema.xml`:

```
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
...
<fields>
...
  <field name="myfield" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
</fields>
...
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
<copyField source="myfield" dest="text" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The are some special characters that you need to escape. They are listed [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters):

```
+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \
```

You can escape them using the backslash `\`. I'm not a Solarium expert but the function you're using seems to do what needs to be done. Probably there is another reason why you don't get the expected matches back.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for that reason and solution for it. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you need to provide more information then. With the information provided it's hard to give you a solution. if your query is correctly escaped it all depends on how your documents are indexed.

Comment: I didn't do anything special. I indexed documents as they are, without escaping. If document field contains a dash, I indexed them as they are (e.g. `foo-bar`).

Comment: Can you post your schema.xml fieldType definition for the field that you're querying?

Comment: Had a look at it. The StandardTokenizerFactory could do some magic but you're applying it at both query and index time, so it shouldn't be a problem. Have you tried having a look at the solr analysis page to check how your field get indexed and queried?

Comment: Yes, here is the result http://i.imgur.com/Hzobo.png Looks like it is devided on dash for some reason. I get no matches with query like `*sasa\-b*` and that is my problem.

Comment: If you don't want to tokenize on dashes you need to change the tokenizer, for example using WhitespaceTokenizer.